# Err while loading RQuantLib

Tags: r, quantlib

When I try to load my RQuantLib function for back testing I get this error that is: Sufficient QuantLib version with insufficient configuration.
Try configuring your build with the --enable-intraday argument.
RQuantLib 0.4.16 built with QuantLib version 1.23. See https://www.quantlib.org for more on QuantLib.

I have tried to update my software but that seems to not be the issue as I have the latest version of R and still can't run my code.

Comment: I suppose this raises the question: what were the means used to install the RQuantLib package?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.